# Launching on 19 api gives an error res/drawable file missing

Tags: android

So I'm creating an app. And It gives me two following errors:

```
11-13 18:47:52.863    9717-9717/com.teamlukas.motivationapp E/VdcInflateDelegate﹕ Exception while inflating <vector>
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:717)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:654)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:617)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:745)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
        at com.teamlukas.motivationapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 18:47:52.863    9717-9717/com.teamlukas.motivationapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-13 18:47:52.863    9717-9717/com.teamlukas.motivationapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d10e48)
11-13 18:47:52.863    9717-9717/com.teamlukas.motivationapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.teamlukas.motivationapp, PID: 9717
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.teamlukas.motivationapp/com.teamlukas.motivationapp.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2136)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:715)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
            at com.teamlukas.motivationapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2132)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:715)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
            at com.teamlukas.motivationapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It works on api 23, but when it's api 19, it gives me this crash. Any ideas to fix the error? I've never faced this error before so I don't know what to do. By the way, MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quote.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Button settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent setting = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Settings.class);
            startActivity(setting);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Gradle app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    applicationId "com.teamlukas.motivationapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true ` in your build.gradle in app module?

Comment: I did, it can't find vectorDrawables somehow.

Comment: Apologies if this is irrelevant, but the error message included with the exception says "tag requires viewportWidth > 0". Does the `vector` tag in question meet this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be a big issue to solve, try to do the following:

Method 1:

add the android:design in gradle

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:x.x.x.x'
```

replace the x.x.x.x with your available api tools.

Method 2:

Inside the activity that uses the vector add the following static code

```
static
{
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

Method 3:

if you using gradle 1.5 use the following method

```
defaultConfig {
        generatedDensities = []
    }

    // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
```

Method 4:

This method will work despite the gradle version you will be using

If targeting prelollipop devices use a selector directly from your imageview

1)  `app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_vector_drawable"`

2) This will be the code for your selector :
      name this: selector_my_vector_drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_vector_drawable" />
    </selector>
```

3) The pass the selector 
 for TextView :

```
<TextView
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_my_vector_drawable"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/selector_my_vector_drawable"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/selector_my_vector_drawable"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/selector_my_vector_drawable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/This will work" />
```

Method 5:

Learn about vectors here 
  [Vectors](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.rdde99hw2)

Answer (score 0):

What is your min sdk. If you mentioned min sdk 20 that time it will crash. Ping me your min sdk with gradle file.

Comment: Min sdk 14. Gradle file will be added soon to main post

Comment: API 19 is KitKat, are you debugging the app through usb cable or copying the build file in to your phone. Try to connect your device to system and debug. Only this problem will occur in KitKat OS.